# I need to flatten JSON data in Snowflake Table1 table, in one JSON_DATA column that has an array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Could somebody help me to create an SQL statement to flatten JSON data in Snowflake Table1 table, in one JSON_DATA column that has an array?

**JSON_DATA**:

```
{
    "scopes": [
        {
            "scope_name": "IN SCOPE",
            "company_code": "01",
            "lob_codes": ["01","07","09"]
        },
        {
            "scope_name": "IN SCOPE",
            "company_code": "02",
            "lob_codes": ["07","13","20"]
        },
        {
            "scope_name": "OUT OF SCOPE",
            "company_code": "01",
            "lob_codes": ["30","35","40"]
        },
        {
            "scope_name": "OUT OF SCOPE",
            "company_code": "02",
            "lob_codes": ["02","03","05"]
        }
        
    ]
}
```

I need to flatten it to:

```
|scope_name    |    company_code|   lob_codes|
|--------------|----------------|------------|
|IN SCOPE      |    1           |       01   |
|IN SCOPE      |    1           |       07   |
|IN SCOPE      |    1           |       09   |
|IN SCOPE      |    2           |       07   |
|IN SCOPE      |    2           |       13   |
|IN SCOPE      |    2           |       20   |
|OUT OF SCOPE  |    1           |       30   |
|OUT OF SCOPE  |    1           |       35   |
|OUT OF SCOPE  |    1           |       40   |
|OUT OF SCOPE  |    2           |       02   |
|OUT OF SCOPE  |    2           |       03   |
|OUT OF SCOPE  |    2           |       05   |
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something along these lines.  Focus on the `SELECT` statement at the end.  The top piece is just emulating the data you provided.

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT parse_json('{
    "scopes": [
        {
            "scope_name": "IN SCOPE",
            "company_code": "01",
            "lob_codes": ["01","07","09"]
        },
        {
            "scope_name": "IN SCOPE",
            "company_code": "02",
            "lob_codes": ["07","13","20"]
        },
        {
            "scope_name": "OUT OF SCOPE",
            "company_code": "01",
            "lob_codes": ["30","35","40"]
        },
        {
            "scope_name": "OUT OF SCOPE",
            "company_code": "02",
            "lob_codes": ["02","03","05"]
        }
        
    ]
}') as json_data
)
SELECT
    y.value:company_code::varchar as company_code,
    y.value:scope_name::varchar as scope_name,
    z.value::varchar as lob_codes
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN (input=>x.json_data:scopes) y,
LATERAL FLATTEN (input=>y.value:lob_codes) z;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot Mike. It is exactly what I was looking for, but could not get correctly.

Comment: One quick note: if the "lob_codes" array can be empty (eg. []), and if there is a requirement to return a row with a NULL lob_code in that case, you will want to specify "OUTER => TRUE" in the final FLATTEN (which acts similar to an OUTER JOIN operation). This was not defined in the original post, so it is unclear whether or not this is necessary, but called out just in case.